# descargar sql server 2014 w8.1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Me quede sin computadora y  estoy usando otra, una con window8.1 y no puedo instalar sql server 2014. Abro la pagina de microsoft y esta caida la pagina... pongo descargar y queda en blanco.. hace dos dias estoy queriendo instalar el sql server y no puedo.. alguien que me pueda ayudar..
Gracias. Disculpen mi ignorancia pero necesito ayuda. quiero el sql 2014 xq tengo un backup hecho con el sql server 2014.

Answer (score 2):

Desde [aquí](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=42299) lo puedes descargar, intenté la descarga de uno de sus instaladores que pesa 1.1gb y comenzó sin problemas, ahora no se si esa es la versión que necesitas pero en requisitos del sistema dice lo siguiente

```
Sistema operativo compatible
Windows 7; Windows 7 Service Pack 1; Windows 8; Windows 8.1;
Windows Server 2008 R2; Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1;
Windows Server 2012; Windows Server 2012 R2
```

Comment: muchas gracias al parece funciona. no entendia xq el tuyo abre y el mio no. me fije el url y cambia dice US. El mio ar. supongo difrente pais. De todos modos mil gracias! valoro mucho tu respuesta inmediata. mil gracias.

Comment: de nada, raro eso que dices sobre US porque a mi no me salio nada de eso, el enlace a mi me aparece en el navegador tal cual como te lo pasé

Answer (score 0):

Yo uso el instalador **SQLEXPRADV_x64_ESN.exe**, que viene en [SQL Server Express 2014](https://www.microsoft.com/es-ar/download/details.aspx?id=29062&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True&40ddd5bd-f9e7-49a6-3526-f86656931a02=True&fa43d42b-25b5-4a42-fe9b-1634f450f5ee=True&e6b34bbe-475b-1abd-2c51-b5034bcdd6d2=True).